# Check if strings are anagrams

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, anagram

I want to create a python function that checks if the given strings are anagram or not, this code works if there is only one word that doesn't match, i.e if the strings are bad and dad it returns 'b' and 'd' but if the strings are 'zippo' and 'hipps' it just returns z and h, how should I modify the code to return all the values that do not match.

```
def anagram(str_1, str_2):
  '''
  This function check if two string are anagram,
  if yes then prints yes otherwise it checks 
  for the words that need to be deleted to make it an anagram.
  '''
  if sorted(str_1) == sorted(str_2):
    return "The given strings are anagrams"
  
  else:
    # words_needed_to_removed = []
    zipped_strings = zip(str_1,str_2)
    for (i,j) in zipped_strings:
      if i!=j:
        return i,j
        # words_needed_to_removed.append((i,j))
        # return f"The words needed to be removed to make the strings an anagram are:{words_needed_to_removed}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Instead of `return` use `yield`
2. Instead of returning as soon as you find the unequal values, store the values in some `list` as `tuple`s and then return the `list`.

Also, another suggestion is:

Instead of sorting the strings, find the count of each character in a particular string and then compare that.

Sorting takes O(nlogn) whereas counting just takes O(n). Though there's this added space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

To return *everything*, add it to a list and then return the list at the end of the loop.

```
def anagram(str_1, str_2):
  if sorted(str_1) == sorted(str_2):
    return "The given strings are anagrams"
  else:
    zipped_strings = zip(str_1,str_2)
    all_letters = []
    for (i,j) in zipped_strings:
      if i!=j:
        all_letters.append((i, j))
    return all_letters
```

However, your code won't work for cases where the sorted order causes an offset between the matching letters. For example: `anagram("ohipzs", "hipzas")` gives `[('o', 'h'), ('h', 'i'), ('i', 'p'), ('p', 'z'), ('z', 'a')]`, even though the only mismatch is `'o'` and `'a'`.

Instead, you could first, make a counter containing the counts of all letters in the first word.

```
counter = dict()
for letter in word1:
    counter[letter] = counter.get(letter, 0) + 1
```

Next, subtract all letters of the second word from this counter

```
for letter in word2:
    counter[letter] = counter.get(letter, 0) - 1
```

Finally, return all keys of `counter` that do not have a value of zero

```
mismatch_letters_1 = []
mismatch_letters_2 = []
for letter, count in counter.items():
    if count == 0:
        # Counts match perfectly, skip this letter
        continue
    elif count > 0:
        append_to_list = mismatch_letters_1
    else:
        append_to_list = mismatch_letters_2

    for _ in range(abs(count)):
        append_to_list.append(letter)

answer = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(mismatch_letters_1, mismatch_letters_2)]
```

Putting this into a function and testing gives:

- `anagram2("bad", "dad")` -> `[('b', 'd')]`
- `anagram2("zippo", "hipps")` -> `[('z', 'h'), ('o', 's')]`
- `anagram2("ohipzs", "hipzas")` -> `[('o', 'a')]`